# Deplyment to azure fails via Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment, publish

I tried correct publish profile but it fails and shows below image when I try to deploy any resources such as Web App or azure functions via Visual studio

[image]

When I opened the file mentioned in the error box, I got this :

6/25/2020 1:49:37 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

===================

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the project building successfully?

Comment: Yes, it is successful. Please help. @akb